# can setTimeout be looped to delay a the loop every time it runs?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, canvas, setinterval

my task was to move a circle to another direction with motion in an html canvas. i tested the loop and it works but the moment is so fast that there is no motion at all. So i wanted to delay the loops iterations . But using **set-Timeout** inside a for loop makes the entire for loop delay and not the single iterations.

```
function Right(){
    for (var i = 1;i < 300; i++){
        setTimeout(function(){
            game.clearRect(0,0,800,600);
            game.beginPath();
            game.arc(x+i,y,20,0,2*Math.PI);
            game.stroke();
        },1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: `setTimeout` doesn't block, it puts the function into queue to wait until the delay has been elapsed, in the meanwhile, the loop and all other code is executed.

Comment: Just use an interval

Answer (score 0):

Use an interval instead of creating 300 timeouts that have to sit in memory.

```
var i = 1;
var myInterval = window.setInterval(function () {
  game.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
  game.beginPath();
  game.arc(x+i, y, 20, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  game.stroke();
  i++
  if (i===300) window.clearInterval(myInterval);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use `async-await` syntax you can accomplish it like this:

```
async function Right(){
    for (var i = 1;i < 300; i++){
        await new Promise(function(resolve) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                game.clearRect(0,0,800,600);
                game.beginPath();
                game.arc(x+i,y,20,0,2*Math.PI);
                game.stroke();
                resolve();
            },1000);
        });
    }
}
```

Otherwise, use an interval as in epascarello's answer.